# Set Dynamic Step functions state machine execution name

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-step-functions

I am trying to invoke a state machine from an s3 event. Everything is perfect and working fine. However, I am looking to name the State Machine execution name with a custom name. Example: s3 object key so that it is easy to refer to the state machine execution

[image: State Machine Execution name]

The above `Name` I would like to rename with the `S3 Object name` with which the State machine invocation is triggered.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Lambda function in between, and call StartExecution with any execution name you want.

Also consider this side effects:

- You need to pay additional cost for Lambda invocation.
- for keeping X-Ray, you need to handle it inside your Lambda code and even also the additional Lambda invocation will be visible in X-ray trace view.
- Lambda could become a bottleneck if have many s3 events.

Comment: Yes, I have that solution in mind, and thanks for supporting that with this answer. However, I am looking if it is possible to configure it in the Cloud Watch Rules or in State Machine Code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no direct way right now.